# Linked Server 7303 Error

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Last place the DBA set up the linked server to the AS400.  Stupid question, I set up the ODBC drivers on my client machine (W10 SSMS 17.x) getting a Linked Server Error 7303).

Do I have to install ODBC drivers on server (Server 2012R2 VM)?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Error 7303 is

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "%ls" for
>   linked server "%ls".

And it's typically accompanied by more information on why the initialization failed.

The linked server connection is initiated on the server machine, not the client machine. So yes, the server needs drivers, and what you install on the client machine doesn't matter. That's generally a good thing, because it allows the server to function as a central point of access for the linked data.